# How to evaluate regressor performance with IterativeImputer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, missing-data, imputation

I'm using IterativeImputer to handle missing data in my dataset and it seems to be a nice resource. Although, how can I evaluate the performance of this regression? Is there a way that I could use some performance metrics as r² or RMSE with this imputer?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

df = pd.DataFrame({'feat0':[10, 6, np.nan, 35, 15, 40, 15, 20, np.nan, 17, 9],
                      'feat1':[0.3, 0.1, 0.7, 0.5, np.nan, np.nan, 0.1, 0.7, 0.8, 0.2, 0.2],
                      'feat2':[np.nan, 19, 80, 65, np.nan, 70, 88, 12, 90, 73, 91]})

imp = IterativeImputer(estimator=RandomForestRegressor(), random_state=0)
df_imp = imp.fit_transform(df)
```

For example, here I could just use it but I don't know how to prove statisticallly its performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to sample out some of the non-null values of a variable as true values(i.e. take a backup of fraction of non-null values). Then set those values as nulls and execute the imputer. Once you have the imputed values, you can use any performance metric to compare the already backed up true values and the imputed values(you consider only the index available in the true value set for comparison). Below is an example:

```
true_values_ix = df.dropna(subset=['variable1']).sample(frac=0.1).index
true_values = df['variable1']
df.loc[true_values_ix ,'variable1'] = np.NaN
```

Once you have the imputation done, check the performance using a metric(here I have used a custom function *mape*-

```
mape(df.loc[true_values_ix,'variable1'],imputed_df.loc[true_values_ix,'variable1'])
```

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely what I needed. +1